# How can I change the color of button, when its touched, in a scrollview?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I am trying to make a scrollview which contains 3 buttons, and I want to allow these three buttons to change color onTouch;however, when I tried to set an onTouchListener, the button, when touched, changed color, but when I lifted my finger, it didn't change.  Is there anyway I can do this?

Here is an example of an onTouch and onClick Listener I have:

```
callButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            callButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b20000"));
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            callButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonshape1));
        }

        return false;
    }
});

callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String phno = "314-605-4110";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phno));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And here is my XML for the scrollview:

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       tools:context="com.google.helpstl2.VariableLocation">
       <ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">


               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/callButton"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:text="Give us a call "
                   android:textColor="#4E4E4E"
                   android:textSize="15sp"
                   android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                   android:paddingLeft="130dp"
                   android:paddingRight="130dp"
                   android:drawablePadding="-8dp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="47dp"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/imageOverlay"

                   android:onClick="phoneClick"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@drawable/mapbackground"

                   android:id="@+id/mapLay"


                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/callButton"
                   android:weightSum="1"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="9dp">


                   <fragment
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="220dp"
                       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                       android:id="@+id/placeMap"
                       android:background="@drawable/mapbackground"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"


                       android:duplicateParentState="true"
                       android:layout_margin="2dp"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
               </LinearLayout>

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/directionsButton"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:text="Come see us"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:drawablePadding="10dp"

                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="44dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"

                   android:onClick="directionsClick"
                   android:singleLine="false"
                   android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/mapLay"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/moreInfoButton"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:text="More Info"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:textSize="14sp"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical"
                   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                   android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="44dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
                   android:onClick="directionsClick"
                   android:singleLine="false"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/directionsButton"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />




           </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the output? Does it change only on hold?

Comment: @Nabin when I touch the button and release my finger, the button doesn't revert back to its original color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color permanently then you should just remove View.TouchListener implementation and do it in button click like

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        callButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b20000"));
    }
});
```

If you want to change the color only when the button is pressed, you should do it in the drawable (`@drawable/buttonshape`). For example this element changes the color to blue when pressed.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape><solid android:color="@color/blue" /></shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape><solid android:color="@color/white"/></shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You shouldn't implement onTouchListener for this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but when I tried your second method, without an onTouch listener, the button had already changed color when the activity loaded

Comment: You already have background drawables called buttonshape for each button. How did you code them ? Are state colors already coded inside them ?

Comment: Thanks, I actually just needed to copy your code and replace my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Create this selector_button.xml in your drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--button color pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<!--button color normal -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item></selector>
```

And your button layout :

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
    android:text="abc"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I tried your method, without an onTouch listener, the button had already changed color when the activity loaded.